# C# app that uses Notepad

Tags: c#, keyboard

I want to write an application (C# would be best, other are also welcome) that works in the background in Windows/Linux, but is able to put characters in inputs and textareas of currently active window, in applications like Notepad, Browser URL Address and so on. How is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the [SendKeys class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.aspx).  This should handle your situation.

---

Edit: If you want a Java solution, take a look at the [Robot class](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17476_01/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html).

Comment: Great! How about other programming languages? Do You know any solutions e.g. for Java?

Comment: @MarcAndreson: I edited my answer to give you a Java alternative, as well.  I just did C# first since you said "it would be best" ;)